# How to get a value from an array by name instead of key-number

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created an object and added an asset `b345` with some properties in it:

```
asset = [];
asset.push({'b345' : { 'prop1':'value 1', 'prop2': null}});
```

I want to push some more assets later, dynamicaly into the same asset-object. So that the `asset` object holds all assets generated in the code.

Later on in my code I want to retrieve the array associated with one of the entries via the unique identifier `b345`. But that seems not to work.

```
asset['b345'];
```

But that results in an `undefined`. But If I try to get the data via `asset[0]` It returns the right object.

How could I arrange this container object `asset` so that I can
1- easliy add new objects
2- retrieve the object via the identifier?

ps: I found this: https://npmjs.org/package/hashtable but it is only usefull for large storage; and it says it can be done through objects only. But I can't find how it works :(

Comment: You are messing up the terms "array" and "object". If you want to refer to your assets by name (and not by an index) you want an "object" that hold your assets, not an array.

Comment: seems like what you need is an object, but now you have an array of objects, and you'd access the first array index (0) and then use the key, like so -> `asset[0]['b345'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no need to iterate through your list of objects in some consistent order, then you probably shouldn't make an array in the first place; just make an object:

```
var asset = {};
asset['b345'] = { 'prop1':'value 1', 'prop2': null};
```

If you *do* need to have both array behavior and key-lookup, an efficient way to do it would be to make an array *and* an object:

```
var assets = {
  list: []
, map: {}
, push: function(key, value) {
    map[key] = value;
    list.push({ key: value });
  }
};
```

Then:

```
assets.push('b345', { 'prop1': 'value 1', 'prop2': null });
```

Subsequently `assets.list[0]` will be `{ b345: { prop1: 'value 1', prop2: null }}` and `assets.map['b345']` will be `{prop1: 'value 1', 'prop2': null}`.

You'd want to make it a little more sophisticated to deal with updates properly, but that's the basic pattern.

Comment: Thank you! I was messing up arrays and objects as stated in the comments. This answer is great!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an array you use an object

```
asset = {};
asset['b345'] =  { 'prop1':'value 1', 'prop2': null};
```

then `asset['b345']` will give you `{ 'prop1':'value 1', 'prop2': null}`

Answer (score 0):

There's many way to do this. To simply fix this problem:

```
var asset = new Object; // new object
asset['b345'] = {'prop1':'value 1', 'prop2': null}; // an object property = new object (wrapped in {})
```

Another way, is:

```
asset = {'b345' : { 'prop1':'value 1', 'prop2': null}};
```